# jQuery function calling multiple Ajax functions; only first AJAX works

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'll try to make this as broad as possible (I'm fairly new to working with AJAX) but I digress.

Currently, I have a function that calls different functions - so, getContents() calls getWeather(),getMovies(), etc.

In each of the said getXXXX() functions, there is an AJAX call to some php stuff - then I use a function to go through the data and take what I need - all fine and dandy.

However, only getWeather() executes - the following functions are never called. Below is a snippet of some of the relevant code, I believe the issue is with seperating the AJAX, but I can't be certain and searching hasn't provided me with anything too relevant.

I have tried performing what I need in one function to no avail - if I play with the order the first AJAX function works and the others are never fired.

```
function getContent(zipcode){
    getWeather(zipcode);
    getMovies(zipcode);
    getPlaces(zipcode);
    getMorePlaces(zipcode); 
}
```

Same as getmovies, etc

```
function getWeather(zipcode){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/dshbrd/php/weather.php',
        data: "zip_code=" + zipcode,
        dataType: "xml",
        type: 'POST',
        async: 'false',
        success: parseWeatherXml
    });
}
```

Same as parseMoviesXml,etc.

```
function parseWeatherXml(xml){
    $(xml).find("channel").each(function(){
        /*do stuff*/
    });
}
```

I realize this is more or less a 'newbie' question, my apologies if I'm using the wrong words/didn't actually search hard enough.
Funny thing is, all the php files are executed on the Network (at least in Chrome) and they are returning relevant data - the issue seems to more or less involve my successes not being evaluated. Well, my first success is, anyway.

Edit:
I also should mention, this is in no way the 'final' code - I do eventually plan to do everything with one call and the like, but this bug has certainly perplexed me at this prototype stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax requests are asyncronous, thankfully they return an object that extends the Deferred object, so use something like:

```
function getWeather(zipcode){
    return $.ajax({ 
        url: '/dshbrd/php/weather.php',
        data: "zip_code=" + zipcode,
        dataType: "xml",
        type: 'POST',
        async: 'false',
        success: parseWeatherXml
    });
}

function getContent(zipcode){
    getWeather(zipcode).done(function () {
        getMovies(zipcode).done(function () {
            getPlaces(zipcode).done(function () {
                getMorePlaces(zipcode)
            });
        });
    }); 
}
```

Note that each getX function returns the result of the ajax request, so that you can use the .done of the Deferred object.

Comment: Ahh, that makes total sense. I had a feeling I had to wait. Thanks!